# Visual Studio (2013), Resharper and AngularJS - angle brackets in expressions causes Tag 'div' not closed warning

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, resharper

In an ASP.NET MVC project, using AngularJS framework in Visual Studio 2013 with Resharper, including Resharper AngularJS plug in, angle brackets in expressions causes HTML validation warnings in the editor.

I believe the warnings are generated by Resharper, even though the AngularJS plug in is present.

Example:

In this code sample, the 'greater than' symbol '>' is seen by the IDE as closing the HTML element.

```
<div>
    <span class="table-header">Description</span>
    <span><input type="text" ng-model="item.file.description" ng-disabled="item.progress >  0" /></span>
</div>
```

How this looks in Visual Studio. A pop up out of view in the image reports "Tag 'div' is not closed"

[image: angle brackets in expressions causes Tag 'div' not closed warning]

Is there an alternate syntax I can use in the AngularJS expression, or some other means of having the IDE recognise that this angle bracket is not intended to close the HTML element?

Comment: What ReSharper version do you use?

Comment: Version 8.2.3, currently the latest.

Comment: Filed a new ticket to YouTrack https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-427655